# Spring cannot resolve type in WEB-INF/libs

Tags: java, spring, jar, war

I recently start a spring web project with HBase. The problem is，spring seems unable to resolve types under WEB-INF/libs. it complains about "unresolved org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration" which is indirectly referenced from required .class file, which is actually in a .jar under the WEB-INF/lib library. Is there anything to be set for spring container to find it？

Comment: Are you using [tag:maven] or building via your IDE? Does this problem happen at compile time or at runtime?

Comment: The war was built by maven 3 and happened when i tried to use jetty-maven-plugin to test it. Compilation was fine. In runtime if i import the class manually in a servlet it's fine too. just the spring cannot find the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I got the problem. It seems that my project depended on hadoop-core-1.0.2 whilst hbase depend on hadoop-core-1.0.0 and that confused Spring. I fixed the dependency and problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that Spring itself was loaded by the same class loader: the WAR class loader. This class loader should include all JARs in WEB-INF/lib and all .class files in WEB-INF/classes.

There's a way to pass a class loader into Spring to use a different class loader than the one that loaded it (or the Thread's context class loader), but that gets more complicated.